# Setting different ranges on a ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, range, scale

I'm working with R and ggplot2, and I'd like to plot a barchart with 2 different ranges on the y-axis.  Specifically, I want 0 to 65 to have roughly the same size bars as 0 to -0.0650.  I'm working with a large data set, but the data takes on a form that looks like this:

```
State Metric Value
AK    A      -0.0560
AL    A      -0.0600
AR    A      -0.0520
AK    B      46
AL    B      43
AR    B      39
```

This is the code I've got so far, and all the data is there, but the negative y-axis is so small, the values aren't visible.

```
p <- ggplot(alcohol, aes(x= State, y= Value, fill= Metric)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label= Value), vjust= -0.3, size= 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand= expand_scale()) +
  geom_text(aes(x=1, y= 65, label=" "), vjust=-1)
```

I've played with scale_y_continuous, scale_y_discrete, limits, breaks, etc. and I can't seem to figure out how to do make the bars negative y-axis more prominent.  Any tips?

Comment: With two vastly different ranges, I'd suggest using `grid.arrange` or `arrangeGrob` on two `ggplot` calls and just reducing the spacing between them.  But that's my rather naive solution

Comment: @Punintended Not a bad idea, but unfortunately I need the state labels on the x-axis and I think doing a grid.arrange and reducing the space will mask them.

Comment: Are you aware of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38333603/ggplot-custom-scale-transformation-with-custom-ticks

Comment: This sounds like it may be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you actually looking for a way to visualise your data without masking x-axis labels? If so, make that the focus of your question, with a fuller data sample that reflects the range of your data, and you may get more useful answers.