# ggplot2: nonlinearly divide scale into equally-wide sections

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reproduce [this style of plot](http://blog.efpsa.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/creativity_sequential.png) (Bayesian sequential analysis), but I can't manage to get the y axis right. This is some simple example data:

```
library(ggplot2)
testdata <- data.frame(logbf=c(1/1000,1/300,1/100,1/30,1/10,1/3,1,3,10,30,100,300,1000),n=1:13)
ggplot(testdata,aes(n,logbf)) + geom_line()
```

The goal is to get this to plot as a straight line. To do this, I need to divide the y-axis into 'sections' ranging from 1 to 3, 3 to 10, etc. I thought that this could be implemented by using `scale_y_continuous(trans=X)` where `X` is a custom nonlinear scale, as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38333603/ggplot-custom-scale-transformation-with-custom-ticks).

The problem is I can't get the scaling algorithm right. Using the value `38` as an example, I thought of finding the lowest matching section break (`30`), and decomposing each value into an integer part representing the section number (e.g. `3`, counting sections from -5 to 5) and a fractional part representing the distance to the next section (`8/(100-30) = 0.1143`), resulting in a scaled value of `3.1143`.

I do not know if this algorithm is correct, but when I tried to code it the results I got were not as intended. The bigger question is: isn't there an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe I don't know enough about the subject matter, but can you spell out the rule for creating this sequence?

Comment: I believe that these values go back to an old paper by Jeffreys which proposes guidelines for interpreting magnitudes of Bayes Factors (which are basically likelihood ratios), but I am not aware of any rule for generating this exact sequence, other than that it starts out from a base-10 logarithm. Specifically, I have no idea where the (to me) non-obvious breaks at 3, 30, and 300 (and their inverses) come from. That's why I feared this would be non-trivial to code. The accepted answer shows I was wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original example looks like a log scale to me, with smaller distances between 10 and 30 (x3) than between 30 and 100 (x3.33). This can be replicated using `scale_y_log10` (or `scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10")` and then specifying custom breaks and labels for those breaks:

```
library(ggplot2)
testdata <- data.frame(logbf=c(1/1000,1/300,1/100,1/30,1/10,1/3,1,3,10,30,100,300,1000),n=1:13)
break_labels <- c("1/1000","1/300","1/100","1/30",
                  "1/10","1/3","1","3","10",
                  "30","100","300","1000")
ggplot(testdata,aes(n,logbf)) + geom_line() +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = testdata$logbf,
                labels = break_labels)
```

[image]