# R language "double log"(?) y axis in plot?

Tags: r, data-visualization, boxplot

I have a bunch highly variable data, let's say:

```
a <- runif(1000, min = 10^-9, max = 10^9)
b <- runif(1000, min = 10^-9, max = 10^9)
```

for which I do require to create plots whose "y" axis is set like that of the following image:

[image]

But not necessarily centered in "1". I need to do this in R. Any idea?

Comment: Whenever I have a question about how to use software, I start by reading the documentation. In this case, I'd start with `?plot`.

Comment: what is the source of your image?

Comment: I did it with Photoshop @Ben Bolker.

Comment: @G5W, @Sycorax: a simple `log="y"` won't solve the OP's problem. I would say the best bet is to define a custom transformer/scale in ggplot2. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38333603/ggplot-custom-scale-transformation-with-custom-ticks

Comment: Thanks for the contructive answer @Ben Bolker

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem, but I has been unable to fix it. I thought to split the data into two portions: those above my central measurement (median?) and those below the central measurement, create log plots for each portions reversing the scale in the case of the data less than the median (1 in your case) and then merg both plots. But I haveen unable to figurea out hot to plot partial boxplots...

Comment: Finally a constructive answer. I will think on that idea of partial boxplot and come back if find a solution.